# adb: inaccessible or not found

Tags: android, google-chrome, adb

I have connected to my android tablet from PC and can confirm the results by running `adb devices`.

Chrome has been installed on Android's homescreen.
However, I met the error below when I ran

```sh
Patio730:/ $ adb shell am start -n com.android.chrome/com.google.android.apps.chrome.Main
/system/bin/sh: adb: inaccessible or not found
```

Answer (score 5):

You have entered inside your device shell and `adb` is not installed on the device.

Run the command without `adb shell` prefix, just like this:

```sh
am start -n <...>
```

Or you can do `exit` and then type the original command:

```sh
exit
adb shell am start -n <...>
```